# How to `np.loads()` an `np.save()`d array?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, serialization, pickle

To wit:

```
>>> foo = np.array([1, 2, 3])
>>> np.save('zomg.npy', foo)
>>> np.load('zomg.npy')
array([1, 2, 3])
```

All good. What about `loads`?

```
>>> np.loads(open('zomg.npy', 'rb').read())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
_pickle.UnpicklingError: STACK_GLOBAL requires str
```

Nope. Shouldn't this work? `np.load()` succeeds, so I know the data is not corrupted:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest sticking with the `np.save` and `np.load` unless there is some extra functionality of pickle that you need. Then it might be less confusing to use `pickle` directly rather via one of the `np` synonyms.

============

There is an undocumented `np.loads`; just another name for the `pickle.loads`.

```
In [573]: np.loads
Out[573]: <function _pickle.loads>
In [574]: np.loads??
Signature: np.loads(data, *, fix_imports=True, encoding='ASCII', errors='strict')
```

`np.ma.loads` has more docs, but is just:

```
def loads(strg):
    ...
    return pickle.loads(strg)
```

`np.load` will use `pickle` for things that aren't regular arrays, but performs its own load from the `np.save` format.  See what its docs says about pickled objects.  And to add to the confusion. `pickle.dump` of an array uses `np.save`.   That is, the pickle format for an `ndarray` is `save`.

So there is a relationship between `np.load` and `np.loads`, but it isn't quite the same as that between `pickle.load` and `pickle.loads`.

================

there isn't a `np.dumps`, but there is a `np.ma.dumps`

```
In [584]: d=np.ma.dumps(foo)
In [585]: d
Out[585]: b'\x80\x03cnumpy.core.multiarray\n_reconstruct\nq\x00cnumpy\nndarray\nq\x01K\x00\x85q\x02C\x01bq\x03\x87q\x04Rq\x05(K\x01K\x03\x85q\x06cnumpy\ndtype\nq\x07X\x02\x00\x00\x00i4q\x08K\x00K\x01\x87q\tRq\n(K\x03X\x01\x00\x00\x00<q\x0bNNNJ\xff\xff\xff\xffJ\xff\xff\xff\xffK\x00tq\x0cb\x89C\x0c\x01\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00q\rtq\x0eb.'
In [586]: np.loads(d)
Out[586]: array([1, 2, 3])
In [587]: np.ma.loads(d)
Out[587]: array([1, 2, 3])
In [588]: import pickle
In [589]: pickle.loads(d)
Out[589]: array([1, 2, 3])
```

Using the pickle interface to save and load an array:

```
In [594]: np.ma.dump(foo,open('test.pkl','wb'))
In [595]: np.load('test.pkl')
Out[595]: array([1, 2, 3])
In [600]: pickle.load(open('test.pkl','rb'))
Out[600]: array([1, 2, 3])
```

Answer (score 1):

This works as a work-around for now:

```
>>> np.load(io.BytesIO(open('zomg.npy', 'rb').read()))
array([1, 2, 3])
```